# I use AuthorizeAttribute, How can I know an action is authorized to current user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I want to generate menu automatically, How can I know an action is authorized to current user(in view)?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using roles if you only need basic functionality.

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials

http://rtur.net/blog/post/2009/06/03/Quick-and-dirty-role-management-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

For something more robust, but very time consuming to get started with, look at Rhino Security:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/22/Rhino-Security-Overview-Part-I.aspx

You can check if the user is in a particular role from the view or the controller.

```
<% if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator") ) 
   { 
      Html.RenderPartial("AdminMenus"); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
      Html.RenderPartial("UserMenus"); 
   } 
%>
```

Comment: If use HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole method, I have to set authorization twice: controller and view.

Comment: Besides rules, I may use some other way to authorize.

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/09/06/asp-net-mvc-and-authorization-and-monkey-patching.aspx